# Handling AWS lambda retries

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, serverless

I'm trying to invoke hundreds of lambda functions asynchronously through looping. When I do that, almost all of them are retried even though there seems to be no problem with the code. When I try invoking them synchronously, they all run well and return status code `200`.

From the reasons mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html), I only find the following likely to be the one:

> The function experiences resource constraints, such as out-of-memory
>   errors or other timeouts.

How can I find the exact reason causing the retries and how I can avoid them?

Comment: Does CloudWatch Logs show them timing out, or failing?

Comment: They were timing out indeed, and the reason for that was that the lambda fn makes a HTTP request and hundreds of such requests cannot be processed at once of course..

Answer (score 0):

Invoking a lambda and if it returns with 200, you will be also receiving unique requesid for every call.

> x-amzn-RequestId

in the response header gives you the unique requestid and will help to trace logs.

You can use `apilogs` to query against cloudwatch logs.

> apilogs get --api-id xyz123 --stage prod --start='1h ago' | grep
>   "6605b081-6f04-11e6-97ac-c34deb0b3dd9"

More details about request id and apilogs is documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/techniques-and-tools-for-better-serverless-api-logging-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/).

Hope it helps.